# Transform linq result to JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm trying to transform this linq query result to JSON data, I managed to do it like this:

```
 List<FormDataEndPoint> formularioEndpoint = query.AsEnumerable()                 
                  .SelectMany(m => m.MarcacaoFormulario                  
                  .Select(f => new FormDataEndPoint
                  {
                     formData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f.MarcacaoFormularioCampo.Select(mfc => new
                     {
                        key = mfc.nomeCampo,
                        value = mfc.valorCampo                        
                     }).ToList()),
                     formCode = f.Formulario.codIdentificacao,
                     serviceConnector = f.Formulario.EntidadeDestinoFormulario.ServiceConnector,                     
                     postDate = DateTime.Now,
                     service = f.Formulario.FormularioServicoLocal.Select(fsl => fsl.Servico).FirstOrDefault().nome,
                     entity = f.Marcacao.EntidadeLocal.Entidade.nome,
                     location = f.Marcacao.EntidadeLocal.Local.nome,
                     files = f.MarcacaoFormularioArquivo
                              .Select(fma => new FormDataFile
                              {
                                 base64File = fma.base64File,
                                 nomeArquivo = fma.nome,
                                 extensao = fma.nome
                              }).ToList()
                  }))
                   .Where(formData => formData.serviceConnector != null)
                  .ToList();
```

This is where I actually transform the data to Json

```
formData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f.MarcacaoFormularioCampo.Select(mfc => new
{
    key = mfc.nomeCampo,
    value = mfc.valorCampo                        
}).ToList())
```

The problem is that, this method gives me the json like:

```
[{key: 'name', value: 'John'}, {key: 'Country', value: 'USA'}]
```

Of course these "key" and "value" are just the names I choose for the properties in the anonymous object, it could by any names.
**But I what really need** is a classic key-value pair json, like

```
{'name': 'John', 'country':'USA'}
```

but I'm not sure if I can get that by doing something diffent on linq, or if I should later get the json data and transform to look like 
    the format I need.

Comment: Use `ToDictionary()`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!